# Dropbox core API on android - reuse token

Tags: android, dropbox, token

I'm trying to use the dropbox API on my android app, and I don't want to send the user to the authentication page every time he opens the program, just the first time.
So I save the token from the first time in a variable called key, and when I initialize the session I use this constractor:

```
AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys,key);
mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
mDBApi.getSession().setOAuth2AccessToken(key);
```

As you can see I put in the key twice in two different methods just to be sure.
Now according to what i could find on the subject, if I got the key I don't need to authenticate using this function:

```
mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MyBroadcastRecActivity.this);
```

So I erased that line.
After that I send the program to do another task but it doesn't work - it works when I authenticate the user using the function above, but then the user have to confirm it every time, but when I use the key I stored and don't do the authentication the program does nothing.
I have tried every source and answer on the web and there dosen't seem to be anything.
Thanks ahead for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set the token key  is

```
AccessTokenPair tokens=new AccessTokenPair(token_key,token_seceret);
mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(tokens);
```

Have a look at their example app DBRoulette.

Comment: I used the line '                AccessTokenPair accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair();
' and it returns null, I don't think this method works anymore.

Comment: Oops, forgot to change the intiallization from oauth2 to 1, this works great.